# load google image search results into new browser

Tags: image, search, browser, popup

Im experimenting with popup browsers for a school project and was wondering if it was possible to use google images to search for images but when you click search have the individual images show up in their own browsers.

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

you want to use the google (search) api or what?
try it with php and jquery / javascript maybe?

why working with popups?

Comment: using js and google api to search for images and load them onto page. but im not sure how to load them into different browser. using pop ups for fun and experimentation. http://bit.ly/iqvGAU

Comment: well popups are ugly, modal windows using jquery / javascript may be better

load them onto page? what do you exactly load into the browsers?
well you get an answer after the request to the google search api and you can work with this answer (xml? so make an array of it and load the data using php + jquery)

Comment: yeah, im just not sure how to load that info into a modal window either.

Comment: well then you should learn some jquery basics / javascript and read the google api docs